# How to download dropbox files into my android application programmatically

Tags: android, dropbox

i am trying to download files using getFileStream() in dropbox api but it returns file 
information only,please help me to download file data.

here is code..

```
FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox","/public/myfilename.rtf", null);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fd.is));

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newfile));

char[] buffer = new char[4096];

int read;

while (true) {
    read = br.read(buffer);

    if (read <= 0) {
        break
    }
    bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox",path, null);
File f=new File("/sdcard/test.pdf");
OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
int len;

while((len=fd.is.read(buf))>0)
    out.write(buf,0,len);

out.close();
fd.is.close();
```

and mention your path like "/public/myfilename"

Here in my code i want to save it as a PDF so 
i am creating one pdf and writing data to that.